# Jquery: Use preventDefault() to disable only the space bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, preventdefault, keycode

I'd like to use the function preventDefault() to disable the spacebar from jump-scrolling down, like it usually does in Chrome, for example. If I try this:

```
$('html').keydown(function(e){
 if(e.keyCode == 32){
  e.preventDefault()
 }
});
```

I get the intended behavior, but the preventDefault function has all kinds of unwanted effects as well on my website. How do I specifically assign this function to say "prevent the default behavior of the spacebar, and do nothing else"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work in vanilla js:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 32 && e.target === document.body) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

explanations:

add a key down event listener on window itself then check whether key pressed is space or not and also check that its target is on document body

you could also check the key like: `e.code === "Space"` but checking 2 numbers is faster performance wise

Comment: You're writing code primarily for humans. Be more explicit and use `e.code === "Space"` instead. Also, `window.` is not necessary, just like it's not necessary in `window.document.querySelector()` ...you got the point. Also, use `===` in `e.target === document.body`

Comment: Also, avoid answers like *"Try this"*, *"This should work"*, etc. Explain the thought process, and eventually post some useful links to authoritative documentation resources for completeness.

Comment: Thank you X-_-Farza!

Roko isn't wrong either and added improvements, but in any case this solution worked perfectly to solve my problem. It's only affecting the spacebar and no other functions on my site. 

Thank you both.